# How do I query in TFS to get work items with specified conditions for ALL OF its childs

Tags: tfs

In `TFS query builder`, I need a query to get all PBIs that **ALL** of its child tasks are in done state.
for example :

```
PBI : User Story 1
    - Task 1 (Done)
    - Task 2 (Done)
    - Task 3 (Done)

PBI : User Story 2
    - Task 1 (Done)
    - Task 2 (Done)
    - Task 3 (In Progress)
```

In above example, the desired query should only returns `User Story 1`

Answer (score 5):

You should create a "Work Item and Direct Links" query.

In the top query select:

> "Work Item Type = Product Backlog Items" & "State In Committed, Done"

In the bottom query select:

> "Work Item Type = Task" & "State <> Done"

In the radio buttons on the left select:

> "only top level items that do not have the link."

[image]

Should suit but there are two assumptions:

- All PBI's that have been committed by the team have at least one task
- PBI's that are in New or Approved are not being worked on

Comment: I tried it before. I need "all fully" done PBIs. your query returns all PBIs with at least one undone task. If you change your query to "=Done",you will not  get a better result. It returns all PBIs with at least one "Done" tasks.

Comment: I updated the quer to "that do NOT have the link". That will return all PBI's that have no undone Tasks.

Comment: Thanks but your assumptions are in my problem :) So I think there is no a exact solution. Btw thanks for "commited" state.

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej - did you ever find a workable solution?

Answer (score -2):

Type == "Product Backlog Item"

Total number of Child Tasks > 0

Number of Child Tasks WHERE (task.State == "Done") == Total number of Child Tasks

Comment: I need this query in TFS not SQL. I couldn't find Total Number Of Child Tasks function. Is there any?!